# Javascript OR operand in select menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I got a drop-down in a form. And I got two area in my form for which I want a box to appear if the user choose "other..."

I've written a function which could work for both of the dropdown, by comparing the string inside the value of the dropdown select (which contains "other1" and "other2") with the choice of the two string "other1" and " other2" inside my function.

```
$('.select-other').change(function() {
        if($(this).find('option:selected').val() === ('other1' || 'other2')){
            ($(this).closest('div').next().show());
    }
});
```

But it only seems to test the first value, ignoring my comparison operator...

Is it possible to correct this?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are applying or to two variables, other1 and other2. Since they are strings you get true, then you are checking with triple equals to true. Are otherx types? Why triple equality?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot write conditionals that way. You must be explicit.

And I would store the selected option:

```
var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

if (value === 'other1' || value === 'other2')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.select-other').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    if(value  === 'other1' || value  === 'other2'){
        ($(this).closest('div').next().show());
}
```

Comment: As an addendum I'd call `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` once and store the value before the comparison.

Comment: Added, was a bit lazy at posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You conditional is wrong, you can't do this:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').val() === ('other1' || 'other2');
```

Because a non-empty string will always return true, `('other1' || 'other2')` will always return  "other1"

You need to check those values individually:

```
var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
value === 'other1' || value === 'other2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value on both option. The way you are trying to do now is like doing `$(this).find('option:selected').val() === 'other1'`

You can either do 2 check like that :

```
$('.select-other').change(function() {
    var currentValue = this.value;
    if(currentValue === 'other1' || currentValue === 'other2'){
        ($(this).closest('div').next().show());
    }
});
```

Or use a regexp:

```
$('.select-other').change(function() {
    var currentValue = this.value;
    if(currentValue.match(/^(other1|other2)$/)){
        ($(this).closest('div').next().show());
    }
});
```